# InverseDynamicsController and InverseDynamics producing unexpected output

Tags: drake

Put simply, I think my robot arm is not making an effort to get to the "desired_state".

Observed behavior: The "generalized_force" output of my `InverseDynamicsController` is not as expected, leading the robot arm to follow a seemingly random trajectory (visually similar to falling as though there is no gravity compensation).

Expected behavior: I am fixing the robot arm's "desired_state" and setting a zero "desired_acceleration", so I expect it to hold its initial position.

I have connected an `InverseDynamicsController` to a `HardwareStation`. Currently, I am simply fixing the `InverseDynamicsController` "desired_state" input port to the starting positions of the robot with zero velocities, and the "desired_acceleration" input port to 0. Therefore, I expect the robot will maintain its position.

I am confident that my diagram is correctly connected; the "generalized_force" output of the `InverseDynamicsController` is connected to the "actuation" port of my HardwareStation. [I've also attached the diagram.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AZ1J.jpg)

I've narrowed down the problem to being with `InverseDynamics`'s `CalcOutputForce()` function. I've validated the HardwareStation's "estimated_state", `PidController` output, and `Adder` output, are all good. But the output of the `InverseDynamics` comes out weird.

The robot arm is attached to a mobile base that is joint locked (but the behavior is the same even if I weld the mobile base to the world). Otherwise, there are no other external forces on the arm, so I would expect InverseDynamics to just need to compensate for gravity.

Anyone have pointers on what could be the problem with `InverseDynamics`? I've given `MultibodyTree<T>::CalcInverseDynamics()` a read... but not with much success.

My code is also all open [here](https://github.com/Michaelszeng/GCS-Box-Unloading/tree/clique_covers_baseline).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get some code from the OP and we found the root cause of the problems: the actuators were added in a different order from the joints.  This case was not handled properly yet by the InverseDynamics method.

I've [opened a PR](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/20971) to resolve it.

(As a short-term workaround, it's simple enough to shuffle the order of the actuators in the urdf).